# Access to control panel Monitor properties on Server 2012 with GUI Server tools only mode install

Tags: windows-server-2012

Is there any way we can change Display (monitor) properties on a 2012 Server installed in Server GUI tools only mode?

This server has dual monitors and the left and right order is around the wrong way.  Can't see any way of changing this without installing the full Desktop experience.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Answer now found, in this case running the following allowed the order of monitors to be set:
C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Control Panel Client\nvcplui.exe